# Flot Charts - handling multiple flots in a single html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, flot

I have a display I implemented to a single chart and wan to extend the solution so that 3 charts will have same properties.

specifically:

1. I want to enable selection zooming + double click to reset the display
2. I want the legend of the series will be clickable so that the series will turn on/off with each click.
   I was successfully able to implement them based on [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015056/flot-charts-toggling-a-series-on-off)

[Here's a fiddle with 3 chart in a single page](http://jsfiddle.net/danklein/ycw41g5x/5/)

Here's my original code (written in coffeescript):

```
colorArray = []
colorArray.push "rgba(180, 0, 75,    0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(0, 150, 100,   0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(0, 0, 255,     0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(140, 0, 255,   0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(90, 180, 20,   0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(255, 236, 0,   0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(234, 170, 21,  0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(95, 180, 190,  0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(214, 92, 63,   0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(218, 106, 234, 0.6)"
colorArray.push "rgba(213, 128, 155, 0.6)"

# chart colors default 
$chrt_border_color = "#efefef"
$chrt_grid_color = "#DDD"
$chrt_main = "#E24913"

# red       
$chrt_second = "#6595b4"
# blue      
$chrt_third = "#FF9F01"
# orange    
$chrt_fourth = "#7e9d3a"
# green     
$chrt_fifth = "#BD362F"
# dark red  
$chrt_mono = "#000"

Chart = 

    generateDataObjects: (all_series, all_series_data) ->
        plotData = []

        for series, i in all_series
            obj =
                label: series.replace /__/g, "|"
                data: all_series_data[i]
                color: colorArray[i]

            # obj = (
            #   label: series
            #   console.log "pushing series #{series}"
            #   data: all_series_data[i]
            #   color: colorArray[i]
            #   console.log "pushing color #{color} to #{series} series"
            #   )
            plotData.push obj

        return plotData

    togglePlot: (seriesIdx) ->
        console.log "seriesIdx is: #{seriesIdx}"
        someData = this.plot.getData()
        someData[seriesIdx-2].lines.show = not someData[seriesIdx-2].lines.show
        someData[seriesIdx-2].points.show = not someData[seriesIdx-2].points.show
        this.plot.setData someData
        this.plot.draw()
        return

    getTooltip: (label, xval, yval, flotItem) ->
        return '<span class="label bg-color-teal txt-color-white">'+label+'</span>'+'<br>Build: <span>'+ flotItem.series.data[flotItem.dataIndex][2]+'</span>' +"<br>Run ID: <strong> #{flotItem.series.data[flotItem.dataIndex][3].toString()}</strong>" + '<br>Result: <span>'+Chart.commify(yval)+'</span>'

    commify: (x) ->
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    generateChartOptions: (legend_container, ticks) ->
        this.legendindex = 0
        return (
            series:
                lines:
                    show: true

                points:
                    show: true

            crosshair:
                mode: "x"
                color: "#FF9900"

            legend:
                container: $("##{legend_container}")
                labelFormatter: (label, series) ->
                    "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"legendtoggle\" data-index=\"" + Chart.legendindex++ + "\">" + label + "</a>"
                # labelFormatter: (label, series) ->
    #                   "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onClick=\"Chart.togglePlot(" + series.idx + "); return false;\">" + label + "</a>"
                noColumns: 4
                # hideable: true

            grid:
              hoverable: true
              clickable: true
              tickColor: $chrt_border_color
              borderWidth: 0
              borderColor: $chrt_border_color

            tooltip: true
            tooltipOpts: 
              content : Chart.getTooltip 
              #content : "Value <b>$x</b> Value <span>$y</span>",
              defaultTheme: false

            xaxis:
                ticks: ticks
                rotateTicks: 30

            selection:
                mode: "xy"
            )

jQuery ->
    if $("#normalized_bw_chart").length         # render only if the chart-id is present

        raw_data = $("#normalized_bw_chart").data('results')
        ticks = $("#normalized_bw_chart").data('ticks')
        all_series = $("#normalized_bw_chart").data('series')

        Chart.plot = $.plot($("#normalized_bw_chart"), Chart.generateDataObjects(all_series, raw_data), Chart.generateChartOptions('normalized_bw_legend', ticks))  

    if $("#concurrent_flows_chart").length      # render only if the chart-id is present

        raw_data = $("#concurrent_flows_chart").data('results')
        ticks = $("#concurrent_flows_chart").data('ticks')
        all_series = $("#concurrent_flows_chart").data('series')

        Chart.plot = $.plot($("#concurrent_flows_chart"), Chart.generateDataObjects(all_series, raw_data), Chart.generateChartOptions('concurrent_flows_legend', ticks))

    if $("#bandwidth_chart").length         # render only if the chart-id is present

        raw_data = $("#bandwidth_chart").data('results')
        ticks = $("#bandwidth_chart").data('ticks')
        all_series = $("#bandwidth_chart").data('series')

        Chart.plot = $.plot($("#bandwidth_chart"), Chart.generateDataObjects(all_series, raw_data), Chart.generateChartOptions('bandwidth_legend', ticks))  

    $('body').on 'click', 'a.legendtoggle', (event) ->
        Chart.togglePlot($(this).data('index'))
        return false

    $("[data-behavior~=chart-selection]").bind "plotselected", (event, ranges) ->
        selected_chart = $(this).attr('id')[0...-6] # slicing the name of the selected item
        console.log  ("zooming in to " + selected_chart)
        plot = $.plot($("##{selected_chart}_chart"), plot.getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions(selected_chart+'_legend', ticks),
          xaxis:
            min: ranges.xaxis.from
            max: ranges.xaxis.to

          yaxis:
            min: ranges.yaxis.from
            max: ranges.yaxis.to
        ))
     return
    $("#normalized_bw_chart").bind "plotselected", (event, ranges) ->
        # ranges.xaxis.to = ranges.xaxis.from + 0.0005  if ranges.xaxis.to - ranges.xaxis.from < 0.0005
  #     ranges.yaxis.to = ranges.yaxis.from + 0.0005  if ranges.yaxis.to - ranges.yaxis.from < 0.0005
        plot = $.plot($("#normalized_bw_chart"), plot.getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions('normalized_bw_legend', ticks),
          xaxis:
            min: ranges.xaxis.from
            max: ranges.xaxis.to

          yaxis:
            min: ranges.yaxis.from
            max: ranges.yaxis.to
        ))
        return


    $("[data-behavior~=chart-selection]").bind "dblclick", (event, pos, item) ->
        selected_chart = $(this).attr('id')[0...-6] # slicing the name of the selected item
        console.log  ("zooming out to " + selected_chart)
        plot = $.plot($("##{selected_chart}_chart"), plot.getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions(selected_chart+'_legend', ticks),
          xaxis:
            min: null
            max: null

          yaxis:
            min: null
            max: null
        ))
     return

    $("#normalized_bw_chart").bind "dblclick", (event, pos, item) ->
        plot = $.plot($("#normalized_bw_chart"), plot.getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions('normalized_bw_legend', ticks),
          xaxis:
            min: null
            max: null

          yaxis:
            min: null
            max: null
        ))
        return
```

What would be the most efficient way to implement this (while trying to avoid code-duplication)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of your plots / charts

```
plotNames = ["bandwidth", "normalized_bw", "concurrent_flows"]
```

extend your togglePlot function to work with one plot

```
togglePlot: (plotName, seriesIdx) ->
    someData = this.plot[plotName].getData()
    someData[seriesIdx].points.show = not someData[seriesIdx].points.show
    this.plot[plotName].setData someData
    this.plot[plotName].draw()
    return
```

and use an jQuery each function to create the different plots and bind their events

```
jQuery.each plotNames, (index, name) ->
    if $("#"+name+"_chart").length
        Chart.plot[name] = $.plot($("#"+name+"_chart"), Chart.generateDataObjects(all_series, raw_data), Chart.generateChartOptions(name+"_legend"))

        $("#"+name+"_legend").on 'click', 'a.legendtoggle', (event) ->
            Chart.togglePlot(name, $(this).data('index'))
            return false

        $("#"+name+"_chart").bind "plotselected", (event, ranges) ->
            Chart.plot[name] = $.plot($("#"+name+"_chart"), Chart.plot[name].getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions(name+'_legend'),
              xaxis:
                min: ranges.xaxis.from
                max: ranges.xaxis.to
              yaxis:
                min: ranges.yaxis.from
                max: ranges.yaxis.to
            ))
            return

        $("#"+name+"_chart").bind "dblclick", (event, pos, item) ->
            Chart.plot[name] = $.plot($("#"+name+"_chart"), Chart.plot[name].getData(), $.extend(true, {}, Chart.generateChartOptions(name+'_legend'),
              xaxis:
                min: null
                max: null
              yaxis:
                min: null
                max: null
            ))
            return
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh7ytsnp/) for the full code.

Comment: Now that is cool!!! :)
Thanks!!
@Raidri, form some reason my legend index doesn't always starts with 0, but starts with an offset of the total number of series.
i.e., if I have 2 series,    `legendindex` starts with 2, etc...

Comment: I haven't seen that in the fiddle, but maybe the reset (`this.legendindex = 0`) is not working correctly. You can try to use seperate indices for each plot like with the `plot` variable (for example `legendindex[legend_container]` etc.).